Book/Notes Recommendation for Quadratic Optimization
While self-studying and planning on doing some small-time research/fun based on Philip Wolf's "The Simplex Method for Quadratic Programming", I got interested in the notion of quadratic programming from that paper. Therefore, I am looking for a more mathematically/theoretically defined entry-level book for quadratic optimization - akin to an entry-level book one would find with linear or non-linear programming in which it's well suited for self-studying with exercises and background history of how algorithms or methods came to be. I was browsing around and found the following:

Optimal Quadratic Programming Algorithms: With Applications to Variational Inequalities

Doesn't seem entry-level into the topic, talks about prior publications from journals.


Quadratic Programming with Computer Programs (Advances in Applied Mathematics)

Comes off as too applied.



Thus, any insight on this would be beneficial, as this seems like a fun field to learn on a more formal level.

This has some nice references in the back so maybe check those out. I'm not sure if there's a text that covers only quadratic programming.  https://ecal.studentorg.berkeley.edu/files/ce191/CH02-QuadraticProgramming.pdf
